# Magento invoice email: ordered items not visible

Tags: php, email, magento

The invoice-email doesn't show the ordered items table (no problems in invoice PDF). My template contains this code:

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

However, this part is missing in the email. I tried to find the code that should generate the HTML, I think sales.xml tells me to look at the "`email/order/invoice/items.phtml`"-template file. But changing its content doesn't seem to have any effect.

Where should I start to fix this problem?

This is the part in sales.xml:

```
    <sales_email_order_invoice_items>
        <block type="sales/order_email_invoice_items" name="items" template="email/order/invoice/items.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_default</block><template>email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="sales/order_invoice_totals" name="invoice_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
    </sales_email_order_invoice_items>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Magento 2.3.4, 2.3.5 the temporary fix for this problem is to update an email template with ordered items with **is_legacy = 1**. For example:

```
 update email_template set is_legacy = 1 where orig_template_code = 'sales_email_order_template';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution from [a link](http://www.fixbugs.xyz/2020/04/13/strict-mode-email-template/)! I'm not sure 100% but This problem MAYBE caused by new updates for Magento 2.3.4+.

From Magento 2.3.4+, the Magento team added a new attribute for an email template, there are a strict mode or a legacy mode.

If you add a new email template for sales objects (orders, invoices, shipments) from the backend, then it might not works property. Example order items grid is not shown in an email. Because they don’t allow us to pass an object to template objects like block or layout handle. Only array or scalar variables are allowed

You can see on the file \Magento\Framework\Filter\VariableResolver\StrictResolver – Function resolve

```
if (isset($stackArgs[$last]['variable'])
&& (is_scalar($stackArgs[$last]['variable']) || is_array($stackArgs[$last]['variable']))
) {
// If value for construction exists set it
$result = $stackArgs[$last]['variable'];
}
```

All new emails are created from backend will have strict mode as a default, no changes to modify it on the backend. You have to change it via database management. Pls find email template data in the table email_template, then change field ‘is_legacy” to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set in database table **email_template** column is_legacy = **1** for the template you use